# RazorEngine.Razor.Compile takes approximately 2 seconds per compilation - is this normal? (C#)

Tags: c#, razor, razor-2

Is it normal for a call to RazorEngine.Razor.Compile(contentStr, modelType, cacheKey) to take between 1.5 - 3seconds?

The template text is quite short, less than 500 characters.  Models range between 1 field to 10 fields.

I have about 600 such compilations to be done (100 texts of a website, in 6 different languages), and this takes quite a lot of time (25 - 40 minutes!)

I am using ASP.Net MVC4 / C#, if it makes any difference.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to reduce this time taken.  As a note for any future readers, I have since then switched to [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) which is another different templating engine but hundreds of times faster than RazorEngine.  Rendering of 1000 different instances is taking less than 100ms on my machine - RazorEngine would take over 5 minutes for the same.